# ASP.Net MVC : How to combine area AND localization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-mvc-areas

For an wide application, I need to use localization. I'm planning to use this method for the localization: http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2010/05/06/localization-in-asp.net-mvc-ndash-3-days-investigation-1-day.aspx

But for this project I also need to use Area, which are defining their own files.

Is there a way that I can use to not redefine the language variable in URI (the {lang} in area?

I feel like I've to redeclare each time how the localization using the url works, and this seems to be bad to me.

What can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of SEO using an url parameter for localization is the best. The drawback is that you will have to define it for all your urls. Another possibility is to use cookies or session to store the current language in which case you don't need to pass it to all urls. Here's a [guide](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html) which illustrates this. Easier to develop but not good for SEO.